# TinyMCE 4 fontsizeselect doesn't work

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Hey I update my application with the new TinyMce4 and I like the new style, everything work proper except "Font Size" fontsizeselect drop down menu.

Any suggestion would be helpful!!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add to init TinyMCE **convert_fonts_to_spans: true** and **font_size_style_values** list

```
tinymce.init({            
    ...
    convert_fonts_to_spans: true,
    font_size_style_values: "8pt,10pt,12pt,14pt,18pt,24pt,36pt",
    ...
    toolbar: "... fontsizeselect ..."
    ...
});
```